# Is "for me either" wrong?

Tags: word-usage

I wonder if this is a wrong usage of the word *either:*

> A. Works for me.
>   B. For me either.

Answer (score 3):

It is not, at least not in the positive.  You can in the negative:

> "This doesn't work for me!"
>   "Me neither!"

Otherwise you should say something like:

> Me also.
>
> Me too.
>
> Me as well.
>
> Same here.

and so on.

Comment: Is it possible to say *me either* for a possitive statement?

Comment: Not in my experience.

Comment: That's correct. We don't normally say *me either* to concur with a positive statement or a negative one. One reason this may be confusing to some English learners is that we can say things like *For me, either (this or that) is ok.* I suspect that many users of Standard Englishes might utter *for me either* in casual speech, and listeners may not notice such things. But if we focus our attention on the structure, we generally recognize it as ungrammatical.

Comment: Actually, just reflecting on it, I suspect that many users of Standard English might say *me either* meaning *me also* or *me neither* often enough to consider a deeper answer, such as the designation % used in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* : "Typically used by some speakers of Standard English, but not by others." See p 9 available on https://goo.gl/K7e9G1 under *Marketing Sample.*